# Cakephp creating new project: error in orangescrum MissingControllerException

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

When trying to create a new project in CakePHP I get an error

error log output:

> 2017-11-29 08:43:50 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller
> class FontsController could not be found. Exception Attributes: array
> (   'class' => 'FontsController',   'plugin' => NULL, ) Request URL:
> /projectmanagement/fonts/RobotoDraft-Medium.woff Stack Trace:
>
> #0 /home/itwolfsolutions/public_html/projectmanagement/app/webroot/index.php(92):
> Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
> #1 {main}

Comment: We need more information such as the route definition, which URL you're calling, your controllers structure, ect

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate? You might having a problem in sending email  while creating a project.

Try to test the email sending functionality by hitting the following url:

`your_url/cron/test_email/?to=your_emailId`